# is there a way to add a bookmark that is different than the text in the pdf document

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

using migradoc, i see how you can add a bookmark automatically by doing this:

```
Paragraph p1 = document.LastSection.AddParagraph("Project Updates", "Heading2");
```

but what if i want to add a bookmark that says "Updates" but the text in the paragraph header says "My Project Updates"

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I needed bookmarks without visible text, I used a hack: white text with a very small font size (0.01).

I also created a style "Heading1WithoutBookmark" that is a clone of Heading1 but with

```
style.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = OutlineLevel.BodyText;
```

This allows me to have the bookmark point to a page that only contains an image while the text is showing on the following page.
It also allows to have different text on the page and in the bookmark.